# How can I get around passing in 'self' to the showWindow method?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I'm working through a cocoa application tutorial from the Big Nerd Ranch's Cocoa Programming 5th edition book (I'm in the beginning chapters).  On their [blog website](https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/showwindow-self/7427) for discussing the book, a user mentions that passing in 'self' isn't necessary and that it's covered in chapter 18.  I'm very curious now though as to how this could be refactored without having to pass in 'self'.  Is it possible?

This code is basically creating an instance of a custom ViewController which will need to load from the AppDelegate.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var mainWindowController: MainWindowController?


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        let mainWindowController = MainWindowController()

        //put the window of the window controller on the screen
        mainWindowController.showWindow(self)

        //set the property to point to the window controller
        self.mainWindowController = mainWindowController
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

MainWindowController class if you need to see the functionality.  It's very basic, its not doing much:

```
import Cocoa

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!

    override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name {
        return NSNib.Name.init("MainWindowController")
    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    }


    @IBAction func generatePassword(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        //Get a random string of length 8
        let length = 8

        let password = generateRandomString(length: length)

        //tell the text field to display the string
        textField.stringValue = password

    }


}
```

Comment: What functionality from `AppDelegate` is your `MainWindowController` using?  Could you use `UIApplication.shared` instead?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Basically in the tutorial we replaced the UIWindow object that comes with the AppDelegate and coded the AppDelegate to load the MainWindowController instead.  I'm not sure how to answer your question so I'll respond with a question, can I use UIApplication.shared?

Comment: I have no idea, I don't know what `MainWindowController` is actually doing, so I don't know what functionality it might need

Comment: @MadProgrammer apologies, I've edited the question with the MainWindowController code.  It's very basic, it isn't doing much besides returning its Xib and a simple IBAction.

Comment: So, based on the [Documentation for `NSWindowController#showWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller/1534037-showwindow), *"sender - The control sending the message; can be nil."* - So I "guess" in this case, yes, you don't need to use `self`

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you share what that would look like in code?

Comment: `mainWindowController.showWindow(nil)`